# Switchstatement stops reading at white spaces

Tags: java, switch-statement, whitespace

So I'm having a problem doing an assignment for my java class. The purpose is to create a program that uses a switch statement to convert letters from a string to their phonetics. i.e, A or a becomes Alpha.

The problem I'm having is the switch statement stops reading at the first whitespace in the string. How do i get it to continue reading the string without stopping at whitespaces
(i.e " ")?

Basically user inputs a string "Hi Hi" the output should be "Hotel Indiana Hotel Indiana"

The problem I'm having is it only gives "Hotel Indiana" stopping at the first whitespace i think at least.

This is the code i have so far:(I cut out most of the letters/numbers to save space and kept what i thought was most important for answering the question.)

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class SwitchStatement {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println ("Enter a message: ");
    String message = keyboard.next(); 
    for(int i = 0 ; i < message.length(); i++) 
      switch(message.charAt(i)) { 
    case 'a':
    case 'A':  
        System.out.print("Alpha"); 
        break; 
    case 'b':
    case 'B':  
        System.out.print("Bravo"); 
        break;
    case ' ':  
                System.out.print(" "); 
                break;
    default:  
                System.out.print(message.charAt(i)); 
                break;
}

}
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`String message = keyboard.next();`  reads one word at the time of call separated by space (" ").

Use `String message = keyboard.nextLine();`  to read the whole line including spaces within.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `nextLine`. If you use `next()` deliminator comes in to picture which is space char. So eventually you end up reading only one token not full string.

```
String message = keyboard.nextLine();
```

e.g  For below string

```
A a  B b
keyboard.next()---> will return you A if you again call then B and so on
keyboard.nextLine()-->will return you whole line ie. A a  B b which you want
```